# How to implement a multi-pipe in C?

Tags: c, command-line, pipe

I have to write a small shell - called shhh - that has the 
following capabilities:

1. Can execute a command with the accompanying arguments.
2. Recognize multiple pipe requests and handle them.

**Example command:**

```
shhh> ls | more | wc
```

I need help specifically with the pipes. I've googled and researched a good few days worth of how to implement this in c, to no avail. Generally speaking, I have a fairly good idea of how a pipe works, but when it comes to implement this multi-pipe part, I haven't the slightest clue.

I've tried researching how to do this and have tried implementing it in my code in all sort of ways to no avail. Either it doesn't work, or I don't understand it and can't get it to work. I've also tried Chegg, but their experts are useless, since they keep asking for more code and the only thing I've left out of the snippet below is my own code that I've written that has nothing to do with the problem I'm currently having.

**This is all the code that is pertinent to the problem.**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

main()
{
    char *path, *argv[20], buf[80], n, *p;
    int m, status, inword, continu;
    int fd[2];

    while(1) {
        inword = 0;
        p = buf;
        m = 0;
        continu=0;

        printf( "\nshhh> ");

        while ( ( n = getchar() ) != '\n' || continu ) {
            if ( n == ' ' ) {
                if ( inword ) {
                    inword = 0;
                    *p++ = 0;
                }
            }
            else if ( n == '\n' )
                continu = 0;
            else if ( n == '\\' && !inword )
                continu = 1;
            else {
                if ( !inword ) {
                    inword = 1;
                    argv[m++] = p;
                    *p++ = n;
                }
                else
                    *p++ = n;
            }
        }  

        *p++ = 0;
        argv[m] = 0;

        if ( strcmp(argv[0],"exit") == 0 )
            exit (0);
```

**here's the snippet of code I currently have:**

```
if(fork() == 0) {
    for(y = 0; arg[v] != 0; y++) {
        if(strcmp("|", argv[y]) == 0) {
            argv[y] = 0;
            pipe(fd);
            if(fork() == 0) {
                 close(fd[0]);
                 dup(fd[0]);
                 close(fd[1]);

                 execvp(argv[0], argv);
             }
             else {
                close(fd[1]);
                dup(fd[1]);
                close(fd[0]);
            }
        }

        execvp(argv[0], argv);
        printf(" didn't exec \n");
        n2 = wait(&status);
   }

    wait(&status);
    }
}
```

Any and all help is extremely very much appreciated. Also, I must use `execvp()` and I must use the array of arguments (`argv[]`).

Comment: Please remove the extra empty newlines from code. Please indent your code.

Comment: basically when you encounter a pipe you loop into your program, and you make sure that you stored the result of the previous pipe somewhere.

Comment: I assume that `arg[v]` was supposed to be `argv[y]`. Please don't paste uncompilable code here. Anyway, after you find a `|`, you fork child and parent processes and then both if them call `execvp(argv[0], argv)`. Presumably, the intention was that one of those would execute the command *after* the `|`, no? Also, what is your plan for the  next `|` in the input?

Comment: Why is every other line in your code empty? I understand the idea of using empty lines to structure for the sake of readability, but that does not work with systemtically each code line being followed by an empty line.